# html file doesn't execute jQuery correctly with a different name

Tags: jquery, html

I am following step-by-step instructions in a book about jQuery. I downloaded the author's zip file, called `chapter 9`, which had the completed files. I followed along and created an identical set of files in the `chapter 6` folder (except for the folder's name and name of html file: `'task.html'`).

However, opening my html file in chapter 6 folder on Mongoose server didn't work. When i changed it to tasks.html, it worked. Why should html file name matter?

[image: web server file location]

Comment: to clarify, `task.html` opened and worked fine, except for the `valid` function located in `jquery.validate.js`. This function warns you when you press submit and your form submission fields are empty.

Comment: Well, the first thing to check is the error console in the browser. Next port of call would be to search all files in the project for the text "tasks.html"

Comment: for whatever reason, it seems to be working fine now with `task.html` thanks